# When I change theme in Sublime3, the side bar remains with the precedent style

Tags: sublimetext3

For a couple of weeks I used the Material Theme on Sublime Text 3, now I installed the Lanzhou Theme. When I activate it, the side bar still have the style of the Material Theme. Any suggestions on how can I modify the style of the side bar too?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oftentimes, it's a restart that helps

Comment: @idleberg mmh, not in this case..